# Spivak Calculus, Ch 10, problem 15: If $f\cdot g$ and $f$ are differentiable at $a$, what conditions on $f$ imply that $g$ is differentiable at $a$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Spivak, Chapter 10 on Differentiation, problem 15:

> If $f\cdot g$ and $f$ are differentiable at $a$, what conditions on
> $f$ imply that $g$ is differentiable at $a$?

Solution manual:

> If $f(a) \neq 0$ and $f \cdot g$ and $f$ are differentiable at $a$,
> then $g$ is differentiable at $a$.

If we write out $(f\cdot g)'(x)$

$$(f\cdot g)'(a)=f'(a)g(a)+f(a)g'(a)$$

we can see that if $f \neq 0$ then surely $g'(a)$ has to be a well-defined term, ie $g$ must be differentiable at $a$.

If $f(a)=0$, then $(f\cdot g)'(a)=f'(a)g(a)$.

In terms of the definition of $(f \cdot g)'(a)$ with limits:

$$(f\cdot g)'(a)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)g(a+h)-f(a)g(a)}{h}\tag{1}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{f(a+h)g(a+h)-f(a+h)g(a)+f(a+h)g(a)-f(a)g(a)}{h}\tag{2}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{f(a+h)(g(a+h)-g(a))+g(a)(f(a+h)-f(a))}{h}\tag{3}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} f(a+h) \cdot \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h} + \lim\limits_{h \to 0} g(a) \cdot \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}\tag{4}$$

For this entire limit to exist, $f$ must be continuous at $a$ (which it is since it is differentiable there), $g$ has to be differentiable at $a$, and it must be defined at $a$ (which it is since it must differentiable at $a$).

This is true for any $a$, including $0$. **So why the observation $f(a) \neq 0$ in the solution manual solution?**

EDIT: I originally wrote the limit equations with $a=0$. I have corrected this for a general $a$. I think this makes the question more clear and conformant to my original intentions. Some of the first answers took into consideration $a=0$ in the limit equations, but I don't think it changes the question at all.

These were the original limits I had:

$$(f\cdot g)'(0)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)g(h)-f(0)g(0)}{h}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{f(h)g(h)-f(h)g(0)+f(h)g(0)-f(0)g(0)}{h}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{f(h)(g(h)-g(0))+g(0)(f(h)-f(0))}{h}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} f(h) \cdot \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h} + \lim\limits_{h \to 0} g(0) \cdot \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}\tag{1}$$

Comment: If you take $a = 0$ for simplicity, you should not write $f(a)g(a)$. Moreover, there is no $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} g(0)$ in your equations. It is $g(0)$.

Comment: Yes its true, I accidentally used $a=0$, and only noticed after the first answer was provided. I am reluctant to amend the question to given that someone already answered based on the $a=0$.

Comment: You should replace $\lim\limits_{h \to 0}g(a)$ by $g(a)$.

Comment: @evianpring As a counterexample to your assertion “$g$ has to be differentiable at $a$” under the assumption $f(a)=0$, take $f(x)=x-a$ and $g(x)=|x-a|.$

Answer (score 1):

As you write it ($a=0$), you have
$$f(0)\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h}=(f.g)'(0)-g(0)\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=(f.g)'(0)-g(0)f'(0).$$
So you need $f(0)\neq 0$ to find that $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h}$ exists and is finite, ie that $g$ is differentiable at $0$.

Comment: You seem to start at my equation $(1)$. Then you seem to move the term $g(0)\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$ to the side of $(f \cdot g)'(0)$. Is this what you're doing? In this case, shouldn't it be $f(0)\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h}=(f \cdot g)'(0)-g(0)\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$? In any case, why do we "need $f(0)\neq 0$" to find a separate limit, namely $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h}$?

Comment: For the first remark, indeed I edited it.
For the second remark, if $f(0)=0$, then all the term $f(0)\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h}$ vanishes so you can't say something on $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h}$ using the previous equality.

Answer (score 1):

The moment you split $$\lim\limits_{h \to a}\frac{f(h)(g(h)-g(a))+g(a)(f(h)-f(a))}{h}$$ into four separate limits
$$
=\lim\limits_{h \to a} f(h) \cdot \lim\limits_{h \to a} \frac{g(h)-g(a)}{h} + \lim\limits_{h \to a} g(a) \cdot \lim\limits_{h \to a} \frac{f(h)-f(a)}{h}
$$ you implicitly assumed all these four limits exist. Because otherwise you aren't allowed to split limits up like this. And if all four of these limits exist, then in particular $\lim_{h\to a}\frac{g(h)-g(a)}h$ exists and $g$ is differentiable at $a$. (The other three limits clearly exist regardless of the value of $f(a)$, so that's the only problematic one.)

However, it is entirely possible for $\lim_{h\to a}\frac{f(h)(g(h)-g(a))}{h}$ to exist without $\lim_{h\to a}\frac{g(h)-g(a)}h$ existing. The only thing you need is for $f(h)$ to be close enough to $0$ for $h$ close to $a$. As an example, take $f(x)=(x-a)^2$ and *any* bounded function (doesn't matter how discontinuous) as $g$. We will have $f\cdot g$ differentiable at $x=a$, and $\lim_{h\to a}\frac{f(h)(g(h)-g(a))}{h}$ will exist.

If we assume $f(a)\neq0$, then that's sufficient to conclude from the existence of $\lim_{h\to a}\frac{f(h)(g(h)-g(a))}{h}$ that $\lim_{h\to a}\frac{g(h)-g(a)}h$ exists, and we are done.

Comment: About the splitting up of the limits, agreed, but $\lim\limits_{h \to a} g(a)$, like $\lim\limits_{h \to a} \frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}$, is not known to exist a priori. I am also clear on the existence of a limit of a product of functions: neither of individual limits has to exist for the limit of the product to exist. Now, since $(f \cdot g)'(a)$ exists, the limit $\lim\limits_{h \to a} \frac{f(h)(g(h)-g(a))}{h}$ must exist. If we assume $f(a) \neq 0$, how/why is it sufficient to conclude the existence of $\lim\limits_{h \to a} \frac{(g(h)-g(a))}{h}$ as you say?

Comment: After all, as you said, we are not allowed to split the initial limit unless we make assumptions. Are you assuming $f(a)\neq 0$ before or after splitting the limit?

Comment: @evianpting $\lim_{h\to a}g(a)$ is known to exist because $g(a)$ is a constant (it's not $\lim_{h\to a}g(h)$). And, if $\lim\limits_{h \to a} \frac{f(h)(g(h)-g(a))}{h}$ exists, and $f(a)\neq 0$, then also $$\lim\limits_{h \to a}\frac{1}{f(h)}\cdot \lim\limits_{h \to a} \frac{f(h)(g(h)-g(a))}{h}$$ exists, and you can put those two limits together into one to make $\lim\limits_{h \to a} \frac{g(h)-g(a)}{h}$, which therefore exists. This lets you split $\lim\limits_{h \to a} \frac{f(h)(g(h)-g(a))}{h}$ into $\lim\limits_{h \to a}f(h)\cdot \lim\limits_{h \to a} \frac{g(h)-g(a)}{h}$

Comment: The limit $\lim\limits_{h \to a} g(a)$ exists of course if $g(a)$ is a constant. But how do we know $g$ is defined  at $a$ at all? The reason seems to be the only assumption made involving $g$, that $f \cdot g$ is differentiable at $a$. This assumption means that the limit in $(3)$ exists, and since $g(a)$ is part of that expression, it is defined. Is this correct?

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer from @SacAndSac?

Comment: @evianpring The existence of $g(a)$ is implicit in the statement of the problem itself. For $fg$ to be differentiable at $a$ it must be defined at (and around) $a$, and therefore $f$ and $g$ must both be defined there. And $fg$ being differentiable is a starting assumption.